# select tag inside php code is overlapping the next <h2> tag to it

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I tried creating different div tags but still, the select tag inside the PHP code is overlapping it. I have even tried using

`````
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="bgimg">
      <?php include('includes/navbar.php') ?>
      <form onsubmit="" action="changeemployee.php" method="POST">
        <div class="row text-white m-auto">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="text-center">Select Username</h2>
            <label>Select Employee's Username</label>
            <?php
              $query = "SELECT empusername FROM empcredential";
              $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
              echo "<select class='custom-select' name='empusername'>";
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                echo "<option value='".$row['empusername']."'>".$row['empusername']."</option>";
              }
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <!--Corresponding Address-->
            <h2 class="text-center">Corresponding Address</h2>
            <label for="empcoraddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empcoraddress" name="empcoraddress" required>
            <label for="empcorctv">City/Town/Village</label>
</div>````
`````

Comment: You are not closing `</select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to close select tag

```
<?php
     $query = "SELECT empusername FROM empcredential";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
     echo "<select class='custom-select' name='empusername'>";
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
             echo "<option value='".$row['empusername']."'>".$row['empusername']."</option>";
           }
     echo "</select>";
?>
```